# Sorting of a dictionary in dictionary without exact word, num, etc. - Python

Tags: python

can someone tell me, how can i sort by key (primary dict) (a to z) and by sum of values of this key

```
{'Valeri': {'Java Advanced': 500, 'Part Two Interview': 120}, 'Alan': {'Java Advanced': 500, 'Pa
rt Two Interview': 120}, 'Simona': {'Java Advanced': 400, 'Java Web Basics': 280, 'Part Two Inte
rview': 200}, 'Drago': {'Part Two Interview': 120, 'Math Concept': 250}, ' Simona ': {'Java Adva
nced': 90}, 'Petyr': {'Part Two Interview': 0}}
```

The result shoud be: Alan (he has 620), Valeri(he has also 620, but a is befor v) ....
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Dictionaries are not intended to be sorted. If you want to access by alphabetic order maybe you could try obtaining the keys and sorting them.

Answer (score 2):

First sort by value then sort alphabetically

This will do `(Here d is your orig dictionary)`:

```
new_d = dict(sorted(d.items(), key=lambda kv: (sum(kv[1].values()), kv[0])))
```

---

**new_d:**

```
{'Petyr': {'Part Two Interview': 0},
 'Simona ': {'Java Advanced': 90},
 'Drago': {'Part Two Interview': 120, 'Math Concept': 250},
 'Alan': {'Java Advanced': 500, 'Part Two Interview': 120},
 'Valeri': {'Java Advanced': 500, 'Part Two Interview': 120},
 'Simona': {'Java Advanced': 400,
  'Java Web Basics': 280,
  'Part Two Interview': 200}}
```

Comment: ah hehe you already posted the best/most pythonic approach I could come up with as well, good job!

Answer (score 1):

First off, python `dict` objects are unordered by default. Even if you ordered them, it would not reflect the change. What you're looking for is [`OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Now, let's discuss the most pythonic way to do this, at least the one I could come up with :)

Firstly you need to pass your dictionary's `.items` to [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted). But what should be the key? Well that depends on the condition, your conditions were a bit vague. You want to sort by both alphabetical order **and** greatest value of the inner dictionaries. This can be problematic if you don't decide on priority.

- Sorting by `(-(sum of values), alphabetical order)` - Will prioritize the sum of the values more than the alphabetical order. (the `-` is there so it orders from most to least)
- Sorting by `(alphabetical order, sum of values)` - will prioritize the alphabetical order more than the sum of values.

At the end of the day, if you chose the first option - you end up with-

```py
from collections import OrderedDict

...

unordered_dict = {'Valeri': {'Java Advanced': 500, 'Part Two Interview': 120}, 'Alan': {'Java Advanced': 500, 'Part Two Interview': 120}, 'Drago': {'Part Two Interview': 120, 'Math Concept': 250}, 'Simona': {'Java Advanced': 90}, 'Petyr': {'Part Two Interview': 0}}

ordered_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(unordered_dict.items(), key=lambda x: (-sum(x[1].values()), x[0])))

print(ordered_dict)
```

Output-

```py
OrderedDict([('Alan', {'Java Advanced': 500, 'Part Two Interview': 120}), ('Valeri', {'Java Advanced': 500, 'Part Two Interview': 120}), ('Drago', {'Part Two Interview': 120, 'Math Concept': 250}), ('Simona', {'Java Advanced': 90}), ('Petyr', {'Part Two Interview': 0})])
```

If you chose alphabetical order instead, so basically changed the sorting line to this-

```py
ordered_dict = OrderedDict(sorted(unordered_dict.items(), key=lambda x:  (x[0], sum(x[1].values())))
```

Output-

```py
OrderedDict([('Alan', {'Java Advanced': 500, 'Part Two Interview': 120}), ('Drago', {'Part Two Interview': 120, 'Math Concept': 250}), ('Petyr', {'Part Two Interview': 0}), ('Simona', {'Java Advanced': 90}), ('Valeri', {'Java Advanced': 500, 'Part Two Interview': 120})])
```

Comment: very helpful Info 10x

Answer (score 0):

This code should work for you:

```
my_dict = {'Valeri': {'Java Advanced': 500, 'Part Two Interview': 120}, 'Alan': {'Java Advanced': 500, 'Part Two Interview': 120}, 'Simona': {'Java Advanced': 400, 'Java Web Basics': 280, 'Part Two Interview': 200}, 'Drago': {'Part Two Interview': 120, 'Math Concept': 250}, ' Simona ': {'Java Advanced': 90}, 'Petyr': {'Part Two Interview': 0}}

ordered = sorted(my_dict.keys())
new_dict = {}
for key in ordered:
    new_dict[key]=my_dict[key]
    
print(new_dict)
```

it outputs:

```
{' Simona ': {'Java Advanced': 90}, 'Alan': {'Java Advanced': 500, 'Part Two Interview': 120}, 'Drago': {'Part Two Interview': 120, 'Math Concept': 250}, 'Petyr': {'Part Two Interview': 0}, 'Simona': {'Java Advanced': 400, 'Java Web Basics': 280, 'Part Two Interview': 200}, 'Valeri': {'Java Advanced': 500, 'Part Two Interview': 120}}
```

`' Simona '` is first because of the space at the beginning.

Anyway, wonder about how much sense it makes to order a dictionary, since they are made to be accessed non-sequentially.

Comment: 10x for the answer